# Anonymous classes enclosing instances

Tags: java

I'm reading Joshua Blochs "Effective Java" 2nd edition. Currently I'm at item 22 which describes inner and nested classes but I can't understand what does he mean by this sentence:

> Anonymous classes have enclosing instances if and only if they occur
>   in a nonstatic context.

Can someone give me an example of code and explain what does it exactly do ? I know that if `InnerClass` is a member of `OuterClass` its enclosing instance is `OuterClass`, but in terms of annonymous class it sounds strange to me.

Comment: Think about an anonymous class in a `static` method. There's no enclosing instance to have.

Comment: Like this: `static class Fact` (`MyClass.Fact`) and `class EnclosedFact` (`new MyClass().EnclosedFact`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("hello world");
        }
    };
}
```

Here, an anonymous class instance is created from a static context. So it doesn't have any enclosing instance.

```
public class Foo {
    public void bar() {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("hello world");
            }
        };
    }

    private void baz() {
    }
}
```

Here, an anonymous class instance is created from an instance method. So it has an enclosing instance. The `run()` method could call `baz()` or `Foo.this.baz()`, thus accessing a method from this enclosing instance.

Comment: Tell me please if I understand it correctly. In the `main` method there is no enclosing instance because static methods are not related to any particular instance of an object, but to class. However in second example the enclosing instance of anonymous class is `Foo`

Comment: @ashur correct in the first instance. In the second, the enclosing instance is the instance of `Foo` upon which the method `bar()` was called.

Comment: Your second example is not valid, because you cannot have the `bar` method both `public` and `private`, right?

Comment: @Waldheinz: correct. Sorry for the confusion. I fixed the example.

Answer (score 5):

The effect is the same as for non-anonymous inner classes. In essence, it means:

```
class Outer {
   void bar() {
      System.out.println("seems you called bar()");
   }

   void foo() {
     (new Runnable() {
       void run() {
         Outer.this.bar(); // this is valid
       }
     }).run();
   }

   static void sfoo() {
     (new Runnable() {
       void run() {
         Outer.this.bar(); // this is *not* valid
       }
     }).run();
   }
}
```

Because you cannot give the `static` modifier to anonymous classes, the `static` property is always inherited from the context.