# Inner Class Enclosing Instance and Scope

Tags: java, inner-classes

A lot of standard books(eg. Effective Java) and reference material refer to **enclosing instances** and **enclosing scopes** when discussing inner classes. This has been discussed in other questions as well [No Enclosing instance error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027537/no-enclosing-instance-error) and [Anonymous classes enclosing instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341630/anonymous-classes-enclosing-instances) too.

What does enclosing instance and scope mean with respect to non-static nested(inner) classes? Correspondingly, why don't we have to worry about enclosing instances in static nested classes?

Comment: I've recently been learning Java, and this question came up while going through Effective Java text. Just thought I could clarify it with an answer for anyone hoping to learn in the future. I don't see how this concept is too broad - I've narrowed it down for inner classes in Java?

I'm happy to delete the question/answer if the community feels it isnt helpful.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Robert - *"To be crystal clear, **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged**."* (emphasis in original) https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ This makes sense because the purpose of Stack Overflow is to be a repository of questions and answers. The usefulness of an answer depends on its content, not on who wrote it.

Comment: @tangy The reason the question might be considered too broad is that you really asked three questions - *(1) what does "enclosing instance" mean? (2) what does "enclosing scope" mean? (3) why don't we have to worry about enclosing instances in static contexts?* - Also, when asking a "what does X mean?" question, usually it can be narrowed down by finding an explanation of X and asking about a specific part of that explanation that you don't understand.

Comment: @kaya3 thanks for clarifying - Is the question as rephrased now better? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have a class Foo with a static-nested and inner class([Types of Nested Classes](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/inner-classes.html)):

```
public class Foo{
  // <---------------------------|
  void hello() {             //  |
    System.out.print("Hello");// enclosing scope of InnerFoo
  }                           // |
  // <---------------------------| 
  public class InnerFoo{
    void world() {
      System.out.print("World");
    }  
  }
  // <---------------------------------|
public static class StaticNestedFoo{ //|
    void world() {                  // |
      System.out.print("World");    // enclosing scope of InnerFoo
    }                               // |
  }                                 // |
  // <---------------------------------|
}
```

As can be seen, the **enclosing scope** of class InnerFoo is the scope(blocks/methods/types) corresponding to where InnerFoo is declared.

Now, if we want to use the InnerFoo class we would need to:

```
Foo f = new Foo(); // enclosing instance needed to construct InnerFoo
Foo.InnerFoo ifoo = f.new InnerFoo();
ifoo.world();
```

As marked in the comment, the **enclosing instance** is the instance(of `Foo` here) we need to create in order to construct the non-static nested class.

Finally, if we have a static nested class, we don't need the enclosing instance of Foo and can reference it directly:

```
Foo.StaticNestedFoo sfoo = new Foo.StaticNestedFoo();
sfoo.world();
```

A static member variable/method of a class is shared by all instances of the class, thus directly accessible by the class name. In a similar way a static nested class, can be thought of being independent of any instance, thus **not** requiring the enclosing instance to construct.

[Source Code](https://repl.it/repls/LimitedThreadbareBases)

Related: [What is enclosing scope in Java?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-enclosing-scope-in-Java), [really confused by "enclosing scope" of javascript es6 arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847683/really-confused-by-enclosing-scope-of-javascript-es6-arrow-function)

Comment: 'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms. The correct term is 'static nested'.

Comment: Thanks, I had assumed that inner is interchangeable with nested/member class. In fact, per the documentation, Non-static nested classes are called inner classes. Fixed the answer.